# Get data from v-select field

Tags: vue.js, v-select

I'm getting stuck on getting the data from my v-select input. Within console.log whenever I type it's just repeating an empty string with no data being sent.

Input

```
  <v-select name="user" v-model="selectedUser"  @select="testingMethod" @input="changeUser" label="user" :options="videos">
  </v-select>
```

Data

```
  data() {
    return {
      selectedUser:'',
    }
```

Method

```
 methods: {

    changeUser: function() {
      console.log(this.selectedUser)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you alter this sandbox in order to reproduce the problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/j243vnpyp3

Comment: @JMKelley Where is v-select control coming from? Which library are you using for that control or is it custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@input` event is triggered when you select an item not when you type, you could use `@search` event :

```html
  <v-select name="user" v-model="selectedUser"  @select="testingMethod" @search="changeUser" label="user" :options="videos">
  </v-select>
```

Comment: My input event is triggering on typing only. Not selecting an item. Though no input data is being output in console.log

Comment: Try to watch `selectedUser`

Answer (score 1):

from my experience use `@search` or `@change` in order to read data at the typing event and `@input` for getting data from v-model after user clicked/selected or finished typing (when pressing enter key)

```
 <v-select name="user" v-model="selectedUser"  @search="changeUser" :options="videos">
```

then
Data

```
data() {
   return {
    selectedUser:'',
 }
```

at method

```
methods: {

changeUser(input) {
  console.log('typed data is ',input)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@change` instead of `@input`. Just a guess as I am not familiar with Vuetify controls which I am assuming `v-select` comes from.

Also, use `:items` instead of `:options`.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#usage

```js
<v-select name="user" v-model="selectedUser"  @select="testingMethod" @change="changeUser" label="user" :items="videos">
  </v-select>
```

Comment: i guess it is this library https://vue-select.org/ as i can understand from the tags

Comment: @Apostolos make sure to add that to your question so people can properly answer it.

Comment: i'm not the one asking :) just trying to help because i couldnt reproduce the problem. i asked him to make a  codesandbox to reproduce it